# get second highest salary of employee using soql

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, business-logic

I need to calculate second highest or 4th highest salary etc.. what is the way to calculate it.
**`select salary__c from Staff_Details__c order by salary__c desc`**

I am getting the salary in desc order but then how to get second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a specific record with LIMIT X OFFSET Y. To get the second-highest Salary, for example:

```
select salary__c from Staff_Details__c order by salary__c desc nulls last limit 1 offset 1
```

Note that offset is 0-based, so the second-highest is 1, while fourth-highest would be 3. There's also a limit of OFFSET 2000, so you'll need to come up with alternative methods if that's what you need.